# I need to make a flush iron trap door

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I need to make a trap door that, when provided input, opens up. However, the redstone *must* be entirely underground. It is okay if the redstone is visible from within the hole, I just need it to not be exposed to the surface.

[image: 1]

Make it work like in the image, but I don't want to be able to see the redstone from my viewing angle.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: Will you have a wall behind it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you want it to open upwards, the trapdoor must be 1 block above floor level. This gives 6 possible blocks to power the trapdoor from:

[image]

However, 5 of these possible blocks would be visible to the surface, meaning that on a flat floor the only choice remaining is to power the trapdoor from directly below.

I'd recommend doing so by using a redstone torch like this:

[image]

Which, without the glass, can be hidden to the surface:

[image]

Comment: Will this not show the redstone torch within the hole?

Comment: "It is OK if the redstone is visible from within the hole, I just need it to not be exposed to the surface." look at question

Comment: Good answer. One thing to note for OP is that if you want the trap door to open downwards, you would place it inside the hole, and remove the redstone torch that is lit up in the picture above. Just adding for clarification, as "trap door that, when provided input, opens up" doesn't necessarily mean "opens upwards" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `/clone` command you can hook up a lever to a trapdoor block two blocks below, and clone that trapdoor to another location.

Comment: This is tagged [tag:minecraft-redstone], not [tag:minecraft-commands]